# Solution of Bernoulli equation with inhomogeneous term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}+ P(x)y = Q(x)y^{n} + R(x) .$$

If $R(x)=0$, then I know how to solve it but for a non zero sufficiently smooth function $R(x)$, is it possible to find analytical solution?

Comment: If $n=2$, this is a Riccati equation that is sometimes solvable, especially if you know at least one solution. For the other cases, some have a normal form (after applying coordinate transforms to $x$ and $y$) that is named, but no easily expressed solutions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.